# Login to Cpanel via Curl In php Work on Localhost But Not Work on Server

Tags: php, authentication, curl, cpanel

guys,
I wrote this code for login to Cpanel via curl in PHP, it's just work in localhost but not work on server & mywebhost,
It doesn't work only for the Cpanel, it works for every other link. please help.

```
<?php

$cp12 = 'https://example.com:2083/login';
$logine = "root";
$passee = "pass";

$ch = curl_init("$cp12");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); //timeout in second
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
array('user'=>"$logine",'pass'=>"$passee"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (preg_match('#CONTENT="2;URL=/cpsess#',$postResult)) {
   echo 'Login Success';
} else {    
   echo 'Login Error'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you actually reach the server port? What errors or output are you getting?

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work only for the cpanel, I tested in three different servers but it doesn't work and doesn't show any errors. but work on localhost